# How to Adjust Window Size as deviceEmulator dimensions on selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-behave

While using the mobile emulation feature of chrome driver, the chrome window opens as it normally does (in desktop size) but inside the window, the website has the size of the device that I am trying to emulate.

How can I adjust the chrome window to have the same dimensions of the device emulated?

Code that I am using to emulate the device:

```
from selenium import webdriver

mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "iPhone 5" }

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
```

It looks very weird to have a website resized as mobile and the window of the chrome in desktop size.

[image]

What is tricky for me is when I change devices the window size should adjust to the mobile emulated, if I was only using one device size it would be a problem, I could simply do --window-size=x, y. But that's not the case.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, you couldn't reduce the size of chrome (by drag) when the size is small enough.(Still larger than the device though)

Comment: That was what I did, but I kept a size that would fit most of the modern mobile devices, I need something dynamic since I am going to test several models of devices. Therefore, I need a way to get the size of the emulated device and pass the values to chrome options("--window-size=xx,yy")